# How to fill in HTML input fields on website using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

I'm trying to create a program that will input a generated string into a field on a website. However, the input I am trying to put in isn't a form, simply a text box that leads into a JavaScript Script.

**https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=360000621393** is the URL of the website that I am trying to use. I want to input a serial number into the serial number field and click "Submit"

When I inspect the network using Chrome, I see that the string that I input fell under the category of "Query String Parameters" with a Captcha field. I have tried to use the requests library to sent a GET request with the parameters, but it doesn't work, as when I print the response HTML it dosen't match what it's supposed to say. I may be doing something wrong, I don't quite know.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#I saw headers so I added headers
headers= {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Mobile Safari/537.36' 
}

#This is the data, I am trying to input 'hello' into the field
serial_data = {
    'serial_number': 'hello',
    'locale': 'en-us'
}

#I am sending the data
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "URL OF SITE"
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    r = s.get(url, data=serial_data, headers=headers)         
    print(r.content)
```

The HTML that I am trying to input is:

```
<input type="text" name="find-serial" id="serial-number" value="" class="form-input"> <p style="">No matching serial number.</p></div>
```

I expect that r.content will contain the HTML of the result page once a valid code has been put in, that I will be able to process with BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

To interact with webpages and insert text, consider using [Selenium WebDriver](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html).

In addition to installing `selenium`, you will also need to download a WebDriver binary. For example, the Google Chrome driver is available [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

To submit the text to that field, you could try something like the following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome("path-to-chromedriver-binary")

browser.get("URL OF SITE")
find_serial = browser.find_element_by_id("serial-number")
find_serial.send_keys("Text you want to send")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Though, I need to do something that can be done moderately fast and something that can be done in the background. I saw that there was 2 requests being made, one is OPTIONS and one is GET, both have my inputted serial number as a query string parameter. The GET parameter is code 500 and the options is code 200. Idk if that helped.